# Can you take Gorrilla Glue in Hold Luggage on a plane?

Tags: aircraft, hand-luggage

Is glue something that is usually excluded from hold luggage on flights? Its a handy thing to have and I'm considering taking a 60ml tube of Gorilla glue with me.

Comment: From where to where? Which airline?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally, IF they are banned in your country, it's because they're flammable.

For example, the summary on the [TSA page](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items) lists all sorts of items not allowed in carry-on OR checked luggage, but doesn't specifically mention glue, but not everything is regulated by the TSA as mentioned on the same page:

"There are other hazardous materials that are regulated by the FAA".

So we go to the FAA site on [travelling with hazardous materials](http://www.faa.gov/about/initiatives/hazmat_safety/) which mentions that for 'some super glues' under 'adhesives, flammable' are not allowed in either carry-on or checked luggage.  'Some'? We click the 'More details' link and get:

> Most model glues, rubber cements, and industrial-strength adhesives
>   are flammable and not allowed in carry-on or checked baggage.
>
> Some super glues and other household glues are not flammable and would
>   be allowed in baggage. To see if they are flammable, check the product
>   label or the manufacturer’s material safety data sheet (MSDS). When
>   checking the MSDS, a "flash point" at or below 140 F (60° C) indicates
>   it is a flammable liquid and may not be carried in airline baggage.

There's your problem, [Gorilla Glue is Flammable](http://www.ehow.com/about_5409782_problems-gorilla-glue.html).

[Their SDS (Safety Data Sheet)](http://www.gorillaglue.com/sites/all/themes/gorilla/pdf/MsdsGorillaGlueEnglishJuly2013.pdf)

specifically lists it as '**2 - moderate flammability**'.

**So unfortunately, since most airlines don't like you taking flammable substances onboard, they're unlikely to let you take that one - and you also have to declare it in most flights ('are you carrying any flammable items?') .**

Comment: I like it when an answer not only gives the solution, but also tells me how I could have figured it out.

Comment: @MarkMayo I think you've misread the MSDS (or they've updated it since you posted this), the flammability is rated as "1", slight: `NFPA: Health – 2, Flammability – 1, Reactivity – 1` with a flash point well over the 60C threshold: `Flash point .. . >250°C`

Comment: @Johnny, yeah looks like an update :/

Answer (score 0):

The [TSA tool to search for prohibited](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items) items yields the following result when searching for `glue`:

> ### Search Results For: **glue**
>
> #### Special Instructions
>
> You may carry liquids, gels and aerosols in your carry-on bags only if they adhere to the 3-1-1 rule: containers must be 3.4 ounces or less; stored in a 1 quart/liter zip-top bag; 1 zip-top bag per person, placed in the screening bin. Larger amounts of non-medicinal liquids, gels, and aerosols must be placed in checked baggage.
>
> Medically required liquids, such as baby formula and food, breast milk and medications are allowed in excess of 3.4 ounces in reasonable quantities for the flight. It is not necessary to place medically required liquids in a zip-top bag. However, you must tell the Transportation Security Officer that you have medically necessary liquids at the beginning of the screening checkpoint process. Medically required liquids will be subjected to additional screening that could include being asked to open the container. We recommend, but do not require, that medication be labeled to facilitate the security process. Many airports have designated lanes for families and individuals with items requiring additional assistance with screening.
>
> You may purchase beverages after the security checkpoint and take them on the plane, as they have been previously screened. You may also take empty drink containers through the checkpoint and fill them afterward.
>
> If the liquid is considered a hazardous material that is permitted onboard an aircraft, it is still subject to the 3-1-1 limitations. Many questions arise on whether an item is hazardous material and what requirements must be met to take it on an aircraft. The Pipeline Hazardous Material Safety Administration (PHMSA) at 1-800-467-4922 or the aircraft operator on which you are flying can assist you with your questions concerning hazardous material.
>
> Even if an item is generally permitted, it may be subject to additional screening or not allowed through the checkpoint if it triggers an alarm during the screening process, appears to have been tampered with, or poses other security concerns. The final decision rests with TSA on whether to allow any items on the plane.

This is the standard answer for items subject to the 3-1-1 rule. **It would therefore seem that glue should be allowed, provided the container size respects this rule.** However if you want to make sure that glue is not considered dangerous material, you can try contacting `The Pipeline Hazardous Material Safety Administration (PHMSA) at 1-800-467-4922 or the aircraft operator on which you are flying` as TSA suggests.

Comment: Also note that flammable glues aren't covered under TSA, but by FAA regulations.  They're not the only source :/